# Plot several random generated line graphs on same plot by calling a function that contains the plot command

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot several random generated line graphs on the same plot.

The `def SnSim(S)` function generates the random numbers and plots them, but each come out on a different plot window when I call the `SnSim(S)` function more than once in the `for loop` further below.

Any ideas on how to get the three line graphs to come out on the same plot? (the code below runs, just cut and paste as is).  Thank you.

```
import math
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

steps=10 #how many random numbers to generate per line graphed
z=random.random()
So=100
Strike=105
N=3 #how many times to call the SnSim(S) function.

def Sn(S): return S*(1+z)

def SnSim(S):
    listSi = []
    listr = list(range(0,steps))
    Si=Sn(S)
    for i in range (0,steps):
        z=random.random()
        Si=Si + Si*z
        listSi.append(float(Si))

    plt.plot(listr,listSi)
    plt.show()
    print(listSi)
    return(Si)

sum=0
for a in range (0,N):
    z=random.random()
    sum=sum + max((SnSim(So)-Strike),0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as Tex4066 mentioned, take the `plt.show()` command out of the loop, either that or just get rid of it and use `plt.ion()` once, which will show things as they are plotted and you will not need `plt.show()`

Answer (score 0):

Move the `plt.show()` line to below the for loop.

```
def SnSim(S):
    listSi = []
    listr = list(range(0,steps))
    Si=Sn(S)
    for i in range (0,steps):
        z=random.random()
        Si=Si + Si*z
        listSi.append(float(Si))
    plt.plot(listr,listSi)
    print(listSi)
    return(Si)

sum=0
for a in range (0,N):
    z=random.random()
    sum=sum + max((SnSim(So)-Strike),0)
plt.show()
```

`plt.show()` displays all figures and blocks until the figures have been closed. Thus we have to call it only after all of the data has been plotted.

Comment: If this answer solves your question, please mark it as answered. Thanks!